# Необходимо написать код, сохраняющий текст из textbox приложения windows forms в определенное место документа Word

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Очень большие проблемы с кодом программы. Необходимо, чтобы программа формировала документ Word и из разных TextBox вкладок TabControl вставляла содержащийся в них текст в определенные места в документе. Конечным результатом работы программы является сформированный документ. Основные компоненты документа: титульный лист, аннотация и прочие блоки, содержащие текстовую информацию. Все блоки должны заполняться как бы шаблонно, то есть всегда есть титульный лист, который имеет единый вид, но вводимые данные в этот шаблон могут отличаться. Язык написания C#.

Comment: В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Суть вопроса в том, как написать такой код или где-то изучить подобный

Comment: Вы просто вкинули своё задание, ваше задание не является вопросом. Решайте сами свои задачи, если что то конкретное не получится, тогда приходите.

Comment: Конкретная ситуация с моим приложением - есть tabControl, который содержит 13 tabPage. В них находятся textBox и dataGridView в определенном порядке. А вопрос состоит в том, как всё это упорядоченно сохранить в формат .docx ?

Comment: это не конкретно. У вас есть какие то контролы, которые вы как то заполнили? Вам тогда надо эти данные из контролов извлечь - либо из самих контролов либо оттуда, откуда сами контролы данные получили. Это одна задача. Где попытки её решения? После, вам надо какие то данные записать в docx - у MS для этого уже [готовые библиотеки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-and-add-text-to-a-word-processing-document) - причем это гуглится за 10 секунд, раз вы этого не нашли, значит и не искали особо - и это уже другая задача.